# pyinstaller asks for dependency that has assuredly been provided in venv and -p

Tags: python, pyinstaller, jsonschema, python-venv

Trying to make an executable python module into an .exe using pyinstaller. So I

- created an environment: `c:\Python39\python.exe -m venv %DIR_BASE%`,
- activated it: `%DIR_BASE%\scripts\activate`, and finally
- wrote a `requirements.txt` including the line `jsonschema`, saying
- `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Now the master command accessing the `pyinstaller.exe`. that per se knows nothing
of the new environment beyond the `-p` parameter I give it, and which I hoped would suffice:

```
C:\python39\scripts\pyinstaller
  -p "X:\paws\src\shared\python;X:\paws\PyEnv\Py39\Lib\site-packages;
    X:\paws\PyEnv\Py39\Lib\site-packages\jsonschema;
    X:\paws\PyEnv\Py39\Scripts"
  -n ptGui
  %DIR_BASE%\prototype_gui\__main__.py
```

Alas, I got:

```
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 785, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jsonschema' distribution was not found
  and is required by the application
```

However, I am pretty positive that the environmental(!) installation of that
package succeeded:

```
(Py39) X:\paws\PyEnv\Py39\Lib\site-packages>ls -1 | grep jsonschema
jsonschema
jsonschema-3.2.0.dist-info
```

Pretty sure that is some beginners misconception. Does anyone of you see it,
and would tell me how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer my own question. Apparently it is wrong to install `pyinstaller` on the base installation, use it from there, and expect everything to work.

Instead of `C:\python39\python -m pip install pyinstaller` I now use

```
X:\PyEnv\Py39\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

yielding an env-specific `X:\PyEnv\Py39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe`. Using that all was good.